# Redirect onmousemove onkeypress

Tags: javascript

If the user moves his mouse or presses a key it redirects to another page
this is not working

```js
document.onmousemove = function() {
  myFunction();
};

function myFunction() {
  document.location.href = 'https://example.com/login.html';
}
```

Comment: *Not working* isn't very helpful, but it should be `window.location.href`.

Comment: use window.location.href  instead of document.location.href, it is deprecated

Comment: try document.addEventListener('mousemove', () => { myfFnction()})

Comment: @Jake not deprecated as such, just read-only.

Comment: > document.location is a synonym for window.location that has been deprecated for almost as long as JavaScript has existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldo use `window.location` (since `document.location` is [read-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location)). Also, you're only binding to `mousemove`, not to `keypress` as well:

Update your code as follows:

```js
function redirect() 
{
     window.location.href = 'https://example.com/login.html';
}

document.onmousemove     = redirect;
document.body.onkeypress = redirect;
```